# If $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) h'(t) = 0$ then $f'=0$ almost everywhere (Edit)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f \in L^{1} [0,1]$ such that for all smooth function $h: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with $h(0) = h(1) = 0$ one has $\int_{0}^{1}  f(t) h'(t) = 0$. Prove that $f$ admits a representative which is almost everywhere differentiable on $[0,1]$ with $f' =0$.

I know without initial condition $h(0)=h(1) =0$ above is well-known statement.

(from comments below)
My goal of asking this question was in fact to clarify the answer provided here [MO link](http://www.mathoverflow.net/a/341462/108824) See my comments under the answer.

Comment: The best that can be shown is that $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere. For example, $f(x)=1$ satisfies $\int_0^1f(t)h'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0$.

Comment: @robjohn we dont know $f$ is almost differentiable

Comment: It doesn't matter; if it fails for a differentiable function, it fails.

Comment: @robjohn $f$ is a fix given function.

Comment: If it is a fixed, given function, then what is there to show? How about we let that rixed, given function be $f(t)=1$. It satisfies the hypotheses, but is not $0$.

Comment: Ok actually that is what I want, Sorry for typo

Comment: What does "almost differentiable" mean? I could guess, but various reasonable guesses are not equivalent. Btw it does _not_ follow that $f'=0$ ae; if $f$  is $1$ at the irrationals and  $0$ on the rationals then $\int_0^1 fh'=0$ but $f'$ does not exist at _any_ point.

Comment: Given the garbled history, I wonder whether you've stated the problem correctly. The conclusion seems curious, since in fact it follows that $f=g$ ae with $g'=0$ _everywhere_. (But no, as I said, $f'$ need not exist at any point.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Question is not stated  correctly, my goal of asking this question was in fact to clarify the answer provided here  https://mathoverflow.net/a/341462/108824

See my comments under the answer.

Comment: What _does_ "almost differentiable"  mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I edited it now.

Comment: You still haven't stated it correctly. (i) For the fourth or fifth time: $f$ **need not be differentiable at any point**. (ii) A sentence reading "$f$ admits a representative with [etc]" doesn't really make much sense unless the [etc] says something _about the representative_. You meant "$f$ admits an almost everywhere differenntible representaive with derivative vanishing almost everywhere". (iii) Except even that is not what you really meant. Saying $f=g$ ae and $g'=0$ ae does _not_ imply that $g$ is constant, which is the actual conclusion.

Comment: I know that **f need not to be differentiable at any point** I myself put a comment on that two hours ago before you show up here (see the second comment). I meant it admits a representative having that property. In your example $g = 1$ (everywhere) is a representative of $f$  that does the job.  @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: So you know $f$ need not be differentiable. So why does the post still say $f'=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the linear form $L_f:\phi \longmapsto \int_0^1{f\phi}$, defined on the vector space $V$ of functions $\phi$ that are smooth and compactly supported in $(0,1)$.

By the assumption you made on $f$, you can easily show that if $\phi$ is in the kernel of $L_1$ (hint: if $L_1\phi=0$, then $\phi$ has an antiderivative belonging to $V$), then $L_f(\phi)=0$.

By standard linear algebra, this implies that $L_f=L_{\alpha}$ for some constant $\alpha$. By standard analysis it implies that $f=\alpha$ ae.

Comment: Much simpler than what I had in mind. (Took me a minute to see why $\ker(L_1)\subset\ker(L_f)$;  you might include  a hint. Then of course what follows from linear algebra is $L_f=\alpha L_1$, which just happens to be $L_\alpha$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hehe:** If $n$ is a non-zero  integer then $e^{2\pi int}=h_n'(t)$. So $\hat f(n)=0$ for $n\ne0$, hence $f=\hat f(0)$ almost everywhere...