# Prove that $\alpha$ is constant on the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and suppose that for any continuously differentiable "non-constant" function $\beta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\beta(0)=\beta(1)=0$ satisfies the following integral equation:$$\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(x)\beta'(x)\,dx=0.$$ Prove that $\alpha$ is constant on $[0,1]$.

It looks very similar to a well-known problem(such as the above integrand of the form $\alpha(x)\beta(x)$, where $\beta(x)$ is any continuous function on $[0,1]$), but I don't know how to prove it.

I'd be grateful if someone could give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can utilize the "well-known problem", since every continuous function has an antiderivative. And so these two are equivalent.

Comment: And for the Lebesgue integral we have this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3355542/42969.

Comment: @freakish Ah! I was going around too much. Thank you for your comment.